# pybind11 cannot import templates

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I tried to use templates in pybind11 [based on this demo](https://github.com/bast/pybind11-demo). Error

```
>>> from example import add
>>> add(2,3)
5L
>>> from example import myadd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name myadd
```

Why does myadd cannot be imported while add can? I can use basic functions like int, double, void, but whenever I try to use any more complex structures like templates or shared_ptr this error occures again (even if I just copypaste examples from documentation).

Source code

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int add(int i, int j) {
    return i + j;
}

template <class T> //template <typename T> doesn't work as well
T myadd(T a, T b) {
    return a+b;
}
namespace py = pybind11;

PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m) {
    // optional module docstring
    m.doc() = "pybind11 example plugin";

    // define add function
    m.def("add", &add, "A function which adds two numbers");
    m.def("myadd", &myadd<int>);
    m.def("myadd", &myadd<float>);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `m.def("myadd", myadd<int>);` instead?

Comment: Yes, but the same error occurs.

Comment: Are you sure you have rebuilt the extension module?

Comment: I ran '''make''' command in /build directory after code edit, yes. I can get some other simple functions (like int subtraction) to work this way, all is fine. But once it's a template like in example I'm getting an error.

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem, `myadd` imports just fine. Maybe your pybind11 version is extremely old or some other build system configuration issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error was occuring in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS via VirtualBox (even with newest versions of pybind, python and compilers).
Update to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS fixed the problem.